# Links below site in google search

Tags: google-search

When I search for some sites like amazon in google , I see the link and description of amazon.
Below the main link I also see some smaller links like Books , Music , DVD etc
How can we get these links for our own site ?
Are these sitemaps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [Google Sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334). You can block them by using Google Webmaster Tools, however they are auto-generated, and can only be remove-picked.

After Google Webmaster Tools:

> Sitelinks are links to a site's
>   interior pages. Not all sites have
>   sitelinks. Google generates these
>   links automatically, but you can
>   remove sitelinks you don't want. (...)
>   Sitelinks are completely automated,
>   and we show them only if we think
>   they'll be useful to the user. If your
>   site's structure doesn't allow our
>   algorithms to find good sitelinks, or
>   we don't think that the sitelinks are
>   relevant to the user's query, we won't
>   show them. However, we are always
>   working to improve how we find and
>   display sitelinks.

Answer (score 3):

These are generated automatically by Google for popular sites.

You cannot add them yourself, but you can make Google more likely to add them.

For more information, see [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html).