# How to display the secondary pages of a website in the search results of Google

Tags: web, seo, search-engine

When type in "Yahoo" in Google, we can get the the first search item with a list of sub-items such as "Yahoo! mail", "News", "Sign in" and so on. I am wondering how to achieve that effect? Anything should I do when building my own website, or it is Google's duty to display a website like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links below site in google search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098602/links-below-site-in-google-search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is sitelinks
google deside whether or not show sitelink for you or which sitelinks and how many (2, 4 or 6) of them show for you. the only way you can help google (help yourself) is to have a correct link architecture. (important links have shorter url level) 
like: example.com/login
instead of: example.com/user/login?something=somethinglese

search engines find your links by their complicated algorithm but these are important to choose your links:
- page rank 
- ctr rate
- url architecture
- social signals
...

and these are important to choose your site to show sitelinks for it:
- your domain authority
- your domain trust
- social signals
- power of your competitors
- and last but not least complete relation between the search term and your site (mostly you site name)

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Google calls them sitelinks and you cannot control them.
[Look at the Google Webmaster documentation for more information](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334).

Comment: Thank you very much, so it means I need to build website with good structure and organization to cater to Google's algorithm. Thanks!