# Google search results displaying links to subpages instead of complete url

Tags: seo

When I do a google search on my site, google lists all search results of my webpages with links to subpages instead of the full url. (which appears in green). Is this ok? Is it possible to force google to display the full url instead of several links to subpages.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links below site in google search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098602/links-below-site-in-google-search)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about sitelinks which can be managed by **Google Webmaster Tools**. In Google webmaster tool, under your site property go to *Search Appearance > Sitelinks*. Here you can modify and edit these sitelinks.